# Parse XML containing processing instructions

Tags: c++, xml

I would like to parse an XML file using C++. I know there are numerous libraries available, such as libxml2 or boost property trees. The problem in this case is that the XML contains [processing instructions](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/pi/) such as

```
<root>
  <?Instruction
   <Info>Content</Info>
   <Property>Value</Property>
   ?>
</root>
```

These instructions contain XML tags themselves.

Is that something that is covered by the XML standard? 
Can I retrieve the tags using libxml2 or any other parser?
Or can I get the tags as a single string and then parse that string separately?

Comment: Can you make a real world example please? That's not a valid standard XML processing instruction.

Comment: I disagree. I know that this looks strange. But the `<?` content is apparently just ignored by most parsers.

Comment: Some parsers, like libxml2, do provide access to the content of processing instructions. In which case, you would simply extract the content as a string and parse it as a separate XML document.

Answer (score 2):

While your markup-like processing instruction data looks unusual, it's still valid XML and `libxml2` will parse it just fine. You can use the `xmllint` command line tool with the `--sax` option to give you an idea what SAX markup events `libxml2` will parse/generate from it:

```
$ xmllint --sax test.xml
SAX.setDocumentLocator()
SAX.startDocument()
SAX.startElementNs(root, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0)
SAX.characters(
  , 3)
SAX.processingInstruction(Instruction, <Info>Content</Info>
   <Property>Value</Property>
   )
SAX.characters(
, 1)
SAX.endElementNs(root, NULL, NULL)
SAX.endDocument()
```

While I haven't tested, I have no doubt `libxml2` will also expose your processing instruction via the DOM API or the `xmlReader` API as well.

Comment: @hfhc2 yes as per the output it should, and the other ones as well